# Replace an integer with a text

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a code:

```js
var number = 0;
var friends = ["Marta", "Anna", "Sara"];

number.replace("Marta", 0);
number.replace("Anna", 1);
number.replace("Sara", 2);

number = prompt("Hey! What Iker's friend do you want to see today?") - 1;

document.write(friends[number]);
```

I want to replace the text "Marta", "Anna" and "Sara" for their respective number. I know the method that I have set here isn't correct.

Have anyone the correct code? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the lines `number.replace`, put the `-1` not behind `prompt` but like `friends[number - 1]` and it should work?

Comment: Can u tell me what exact output you want then i can help u!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need replace as you're trying to access values by index

```js
var friends = ["Marta", "Anna", "Sara"];

let number = prompt("Hey! What Iker's friend do you want to see today?") - 1;

document.write(friends[number] || 'Not in friends list :(');
```

And also `Number` don't have replace method `String` do have

---

> Update: and can I replace an String on the prompt(); like "Marta" to 1?

```js
var friendsArr = ["Marta", "Anna", "Sara"];
var friendsObj = {"Marta":1, "Anna":2, "Sara":3};

let input = prompt("Hey! What Iker's friend do you want to see today?")

let op = parseInt(input) ? friendsArr[input] : friendsObj[input] 

document.write(op || 'Not in friends list :(');
```

Comment: and can I replace an String on the prompt(); like "Marta" to 1?

Comment: @AntonioPeñaSantana yes see the second snippet

Comment: if you put "Anna" in the prompt(); in the document.write(); will appear the number 2, and if you put "1" in the prompt(); in the document.write(); will appear "Not in friends list :("

How can I replace "Anna" for "Anna" and "2" for "Anna"?

Comment: @AntonioPeñaSantana you need two way binding for that. so you can check input value, if it is convert-able to number than access `friendsArr` or else access `friendsObj` see the see second snippet